# MPI slave sends data, but only a quarter of it is correct

Tags: multithreading, multidimensional-array, vector, parallel-processing, mpi

I changed my question, since I can't ask another question, from the question of which variables to send and receive to the one below. Hopefully this is a more appropriate question.

I am trying to collect the data that was split up across my processors, but only a quarter of it comes back correctly. I am assigning (num loops)/(num procs) number of loops to each processor (user is forced to use an integer number of processors for the number of iterations). While using 5 processors and 200 iterations, each slave calculates all 40 values properly, but somehow only a quarter make it back to the master properly. I scaled it up to 400 iterations and still only a quarter made it back to the master properly. I am wondering if I need a wait or something to make sure it finishes reading from one processor to go to the next? The MPI part of the code is below with all of the math removed.

```
#define MASTER 0
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
MPI_Status status;
int rank,size,name_len;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

chunksize = (NumEnergies / size);    
if (rank == MASTER)
{
    offset = chunksize;
    for (dest=1; dest<size; dest++)
    {
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        offset = offset + chunksize;
    }

    //master does its calcs for CrossSections and DiffCrossSections

    for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        source = i;
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&CrossSections[offset][1], chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        MPI_Recv(&DiffCrossSections[0][offset+1], (181)*chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
}


if (rank > MASTER)
{
    /* Receive my portion of array from the master task */
    source = MASTER;
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    std::cout<<"Processor: "<<processor_name<<"   rank:"<<rank<<"  Energies="<<CrossSections[offset][0]<<" - "<<CrossSections[offset+chunksize-1][0]<<std::endl;

    /* Each task does its part of the work */

    /* Send task results back to the master task */
    dest = MASTER;
    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&CrossSections[offset][1], chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&DiffCrossSections[0][offset+1], (181)*chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

I read out the values in each of the slaves and all values are correct, though of course jumbled around. 3/4 of them send back 0s, which is what I initialize the vectors to. So, it seems like they are just keeping their initialized values, not actually being sent garbage. Any hints on as to what could be causing it to return only a quarter of the values correctly? It is a quarter every time, it does not change.

Thanks!

Comment: OpenMP is for shared memory but MPI is for distributed memory. There is no such thing as shared variable in MPI, and it is up to you to communicate data between MPI tasks.

Comment: When I see examples, not every variable that is initiated outside of the MPI initialization is sent/received. That's what I meant by shared. How do you determine which variables need to be sent and received using MPI functions? If I don't send and receive, are they performed on every task? So, the entire program is run on each task, but only code that is specified for a certain task is done on that task and the only things shared are sent and received?

Comment: From the question it is unclear what you really want to know but it is clear that you lack a strong understanding of the fundamentals of MPI. I would recommend turning to basic MPI learning materials. If you then have some **specific** questions regarding **actual code**, it's the right time to post it here on SO.

Comment: It seeming like I don't know MPI well was not accidental. I thought I made that clear purposefully. I had said I am working through examples and documentation but I didn't realize that MPI runs the ENTIRE code on all of the threads, even if it is before MPI_INIT (I couldn't find that answer). You don't just do parts in parallel like OpenMP, it is all in parallel and you just tell which threads what to communicate and what to/what not to do. Sorry for the unclear question. I will come back with code.

Comment: Are you sure a slave computes from `CrossSections[offset][1]` and not from `CrossSections[0][1]` ? How did you declare and allocate `CrossSections` ?

Comment: I fixed the issue by using a 1D buffer vector. I believe the way I have CrossSections declared, I was scanning through the vector incorrectly during MPI_send. It might have to do with how the memory is allocated in the 2 dimensions. I might try to switch the indices to see if it outputs the answer correctly, but I would have to change all of my functions, so the buffer will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was with how send goes through the memory allocated to the vector. It works fine when I use a 1D buffer to pass the results, which makes me feel like the data I wanted to pass was not in all in a contiguous memory block. So, perhaps reversing the indices while allocating the vector would make the memory I want to access contiguous. But, perhaps the way I have it is an "ordered pair" arrangement, not what I actually want it to be. I will have to do the same for DiffCrossSections.

Edit: I transposed CrossSections and DiffCrossSections in their initializations, and it fixed the issue. So, it did appear to be that I was sending data in memory that I thought was contiguous but wasn't.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double > > DiffCrossSections (NumEnergies+1,std::vector<double>(181,0.0));
std::vector< std::vector<double > > CrossSections (2, std::vector<double> (NumEnergies,0.0));

#define MASTER 0
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
MPI_Status status;
int rank,size,name_len;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

chunksize = (NumEnergies / size);    
if (rank == MASTER)
{
    offset = chunksize;
    for (dest=1; dest<size; dest++)
    {
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        offset = offset + chunksize;
    }

    //master does its calcs for CrossSections and DiffCrossSections

    for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        source = i;
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&CorssSections[1][offset], chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        MPI_Recv(&DiffCrossSections[offset+1][0], (181)*chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
}


if (rank > MASTER)
{
    /* Receive my portion of array from the master task */
    source = MASTER;
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    std::cout<<"Processor: "<<processor_name<<"   rank:"<<rank<<"  Energies="<<CrossSections[0][offset]<<" - "<<CrossSections[0][offset+chunksize-1]<<std::endl;

    /* Each task does its part of the work */

    /* Send task results back to the master task */
    dest = MASTER;
    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&CrossSections[1][offset], chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&DiffCrossSections[offset+1][0], (181)*chunksize, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```